# Is it a good design to use two separate repository instances - one as scoped and one as singleton for the same tables in a .NET core application?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm working on a .NET core app that has two use cases. One is a normal HTTP post API end point, where I create some records in some SQL server tables after performing business logic.

Another workflow is a RabbitMQ consumer that is going to consume message periodically and update the same set of tables.

For the API endpoints, I inject my repository instance as a scoped dependency. But for the RabbitMQ consumer, I'm forced to use all my dependencies as a singleton since the consumer in itself is a singleton. Another reason for singleton is that the consumer uses a TPL dataflow pipeline which needs to be singleton as well to ensure ordered consumption of messages. The following is the repository interface.

```
public interface ISessionRepository
    {
        Task<Result<Session>> GetAsync(int sessionId);

        Task<Result<bool>> UpdateAsync(Session session);
    }
```

I have a two copies of the above interface in different names. But implementation uses the same tables. The singleton repository implementation uses Dapper to update whereas the scoped repository instance uses Entity Framework to update.

There is a possibility that both the HTTP workflow and the RabbitMQ workflow may overlap meaning that when the consumer is trying to update the tables, the HTTP workflow may also attempt to update or delete the table records.

Is this a serious design flaw? The possibility for overlap is minimal, can this be addressed just by handling DB exceptions and implementing retries in my repository implementation? Or are there any alternatives to handle this situation.

Answer (score -1):

**Possible Design Concerns**

Concurrency Control: Without proper concurrency control, simultaneous updates from your HTTP API and RabbitMQ consumer can lead to data inconsistencies, race conditions, or even data loss.

*Transaction Management*: Different handling mechanisms between Dapper (used in your singleton scenario) and Entity Framework (used in your scoped scenario) can lead to discrepancies in how transactions are managed.

*Scalability*: As your application grows, the singleton approach in the RabbitMQ consumer might become a bottleneck, and managing state effectively across the two different flows can become increasingly complex.

**Addressing the Concerns**

Optimistic Concurrency Control: Implement optimistic concurrency control in your SQL Server tables. This typically involves using a version number or timestamp column in your tables. When you perform an update, you check that the version hasn't changed since you last read it. If there's a conflict, you can then retry the operation. This approach is well-supported by Entity Framework and can also be implemented with Dapper.

*Unified Data Access Strategy*: Consider using a single data access strategy (either Dapper or Entity Framework) throughout your application. This can simplify transaction management and ensure consistent behavior across different parts of your application.

*Database Locks*: As a more immediate solution, you can implement database-level locks to ensure that only one operation can modify a record at a time. However, this can reduce the throughput of your application and should be used judiciously.

*Handling Retries and Deadlocks*: Implement retry logic in your repository methods to handle transient database errors, including deadlocks. The strategy should include exponential backoff to avoid exacerbating any contention issues.

*Eventual Consistency*: If strict consistency is not required at all times, consider an approach where the RabbitMQ consumer updates are processed asynchronously, and your application can tolerate eventual consistency. This can reduce the immediate strain on your database but requires careful design to ensure system integrity.

*Domain Events*: Instead of directly updating the tables from two different sources, consider using domain events that are handled in a consistent manner, whether they originate from the HTTP API or the RabbitMQ consumer. This can help in maintaining a consistent approach to business logic and data manipulation.

**Conclusion**:
While handling database exceptions and implementing retries can mitigate some issues, it's usually better to address the underlying design to ensure data consistency and application scalability. Analyzing the necessity of using both Dapper and Entity Framework and moving towards a unified approach can significantly reduce complexity and potential issues.

Remember, the right solution depends on your specific requirements, including the acceptable level of consistency, throughput, and scalability. If the overlap is minimal and controlled, your current approach might be adequate with improved error handling and retries. However, if you anticipate growth or increased overlap, consider adopting more robust strategies to ensure consistency and reliability.